# Avoid sql injection with query by ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, postgresql-9.3

I need to query by the method `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(USER_INPUT)`

The query string is given by **USER INPUT** (They can query by URL with any `time period`, `product_type` )

How do I prevent SQL inject ? To avoid any damage for my system ?

Is it possible to limit user can only query for `SELECT` except for `DELETE, TRUNCATE, INSERT, UPDATE ...`

Comment: It seems weird to want to have that. Is it possible to have a more fine grained set of possible commands? Also the way you put it nothing is an SQL injection, it is just user input. You need to provide some rules based on which you 'll come up with a policy for accepting user input.

Comment: You can't. You're accepting SQL from the user. It doesn't make sense to prevent SQL "injection" when you're opening the doors and saying "come right in, run whatever SQL you like". Are you trying to *filter* user input to restrict what *kinds of SQL commands* may be run?

Answer (score 4):

If I understand what you want correctly, you don't actually want to prevent SQL injection at all. In fact, you're permitting your app to run arbitrary SQL by design.

What you seem to want is to restrict *what* SQL may be run.

This is doomed to fail. At least on PostgreSQL a `SELECT` can run all sorts of functions you don't want ordinary users running if invoked with a privileged user. They can also access system catalogs full of information you don't necessarily want them knowing.

Filtering by command type *will not work* even if you successfully write a parser that prevents the inclusion of multiple commands in a single SQL string. That's not as simple as you might hope; you must handle `standard_conforming_strings` on and off for literals, `$$` quoting, identifier quoting, `--` and `/* */` comments, etc. You *will* get it wrong and have holes in your filter and/or prohibit perfectly legal commands.

A slightly safer approach is to use a less-privileged database role when running commands from the user. This role should only have the right to read what you explicitly `GRANT`ed it. It should have no `INSERT`, `UPDATE` or `DELETE` rights, no table or other object ownership, and of course not be the superuser. You let the user send whatever SQL they want, or make a cursory attempt at filtering it, but you rely on the database's access rights to really stop them doing anything naughty. You can also `SET TRANSACTION READ ONLY` ... but be aware that such a setting is mostly advisory, and not a hard restriction.

As far as I know Rails doesn't make it easy to get an unprivileged connection or have your app work with a less privileged connection day-to-day than for upgrades. That's because Rails likes to do everything as a single database user, usually a highly privileged one that owns all the objects so it can do migrations whenever it feels like it. It's all part of the Rails/ActiveRecord philosophy that the database isn't much more than a dumb row store.

Even with more flexible frameworks it's still a pain to get a connection with different user rights. `SET ROLE` or `SET SESSION AUTHORIZATION` work, but both can be reset to gain a privileged connection, there's no notion of dropping privileges in PostgreSQL at the moment. There are too many ways a user might sneak a `RESET ROLE` or `RESET SESSION AUTHORIZATION` through for me to be comfortable using them with arbitrary SQL. So you have to actually make a new connection with different credentials.

That's what I'd do. Make a new connection with different credentials and run the SQL as a very restricted user account. You can do things like `REVOKE` the ability to view `pg_proc` and `pg_class` from this account, restricting how much of the system catalogs it can see, and you can grant it only the minimum access to your tables that you really need it to have. (Remember to `REVOKE CREATE ON SCHEMA public FROM public` then `GRANT` it back to just the users you want to be able to make tables).

Comment: Rails ActiveRecord (like all ORMs including the ones I've written) is garbage in a straightjacket. If you bypass all the "friendly" and "portable" stuff and talk to the underlying [`pg` interface](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/ged/ruby-pg) you can have more flexibility. The whole "send user-supplied SQL into the database" thing still gives me the willies though.

Comment: @muistooshort Yup. I wouldn't do it in most cases - i'd use a restricted query DSL if possible. I can imagine circumstances where it'd be necessary ... but for most of those I'd rather let the user in directly via psql with a restricted role.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is [quote](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/Quoting.html)

```
sql = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.quote( potentially harmful string )
res = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
```

You can also use [sanitize_sql_array](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/sanitize_sql_array/class):

```
sql = ActiveRecord::Base.send(:sanitize_sql_array, sql_array)
res = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
```

Comment: the OP doesn't simply want sanitization - he wants to reject the query if it isn't a `SELECT`

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar problem trying to create a kind of "dataclips" (Heroku style) inside my own application. Although I would state my problem as "How to let a user of my application run arbitrary SQL in a read-only mode".

The most elegant solution without the need for specific database users was:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
  results = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all sql
  do_your_stuff_here_with results
  raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
end
```

The raise ActiveRecord::Rollback will rollback the transaction preventing anything to be persisted, the exception in not re-raised outside of the transaction block.

The select_all prevents the use of multiple statements since it deals with the prepared statement interface in libpq.

Answer (score 0):

I would create another user on that database that has only granted the right to run `SELECT` queries. Than use this restricted user account to run the queries generated from user input.